# Sample Size Estimation with unknown variance

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, estimation

[image]

After spending a lot of time I'm still nowhere.

What I have:

Let d denote the desired margin of error so that the interval for µ is of width 2d. Let (1 − α)
denote the probability associated with the margin of error. Then
$(\frac{z_{α/2}σ}{d})^2$

Using the estimator $X∼N(θ, θ(1 − θ)/n)$

Do I simply plug this into $(\frac{z_{α/2}σ}{d})^2$ ?

2nd Question. What happens to n if there is no idea about the value of $θ$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, if you mean what I think you mean. Your work was a little hard for me to follow. This is how I would do it:
   $$P(|\theta-\hat\theta|<d|) = P(|X-\hat X|< nd) = P\left(\frac{|X-\hat X|}{\sigma_x} < \frac{nd}{\sigma_x}\right) < z_{\alpha/2}$$
   where $n\theta = \hat X$ and $n\hat\theta = X$.

$$z_{\alpha/2} = \frac{nd}{\sigma_x}$$
Now $\sigma_x^2 \approx n\theta(1-\theta)$, so 
$$z_{\alpha/2} = \frac{\sqrt{n_{min}}d}{\sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}}$$
$$\sqrt{n_{min}} = \sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}\frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{d}$$
$$n \geq n_{min} = \theta(1-\theta)\left(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{d}\right)^2$$

2. You have to do something to get information about the value of $\theta$. Take a preliminary sample, estimate it based on preexisting data, or make a guess.

Comment: Can you explain why the line $$\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}\frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{d}$$
$$n \geq \theta(1-\theta)\left(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{d}\right)^2$$ becomes $\geq$ and not =?

Comment: Also I for the question I thought that I can replace the $θ$ with the estimator.

Comment: @Nick, it's a bit of an abuse of notation. There should be an inequality throughout, I just didn't feel like keeping track of what is greater than/less than what. I fixed it.

You can't replace it with the estimator because by the time you have X, the number of successes, the trial is already over, so you can't exactly determine the sample size. But if you do a preliminary sample, you can certainly replace it with the preliminary value of the estimator.